# How to redirect to another page after form action?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using Simple Form (getsimpleform.com) to email the HTML form contents to my email. The problem I am facing is that the HTML Form action is handled by [getsimpleform](http://getsimpleform.com) so when the user clicks on submit button of the form, they are redirected to `https://getsimpleform.com/` but I want them to stay be redirected to another page (i.e. contact.html).

So I want the form action to be performed but at the same time, I want the user to be redirected to another web page.

Thanks.

Comment: change form's action attribute to your own's url

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: use ajax to send form data and change `action="yourdomain.com/contact.html"`

Answer (score 2):

Just fill up your action attribute

```
<form action="next-page-please-url">
<button>butt</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an action calback on your button, for example :

in yout HTML

```
<form>
...
<input type="submit" onclick="redirect()">
</form>
```

and in your javascript :

```
var redirect = function(){
   document.location.href="contact.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change the action url of the form to your domain name

From

```
action="https://getsimpleform.com/"
```

To

```
action="https://YourDomain.com/"
```

and then on your php or whatever server side language you are using you can redirect e.g. I will use php example.

```
header('Location: http://www.YourDomain.com/OtherPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [their official page recommendation on redirect](https://getsimpleform.com/)

```
  <input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='https://yourdomain.com/contact.html' />
```

Try to insert it into the form and see whether it solves your problem.

P.S. don't forget to change [yourdomain] to your actual domain.